# what is cloud container? Does it differ from a data center?

Tags: cloud

Are there only 2 types of Cloud container- federated and shared. What does it take to setup a cloud container. Is it always good choice to setup cloud container instead of data center?

By cloud container i understand it is for larger setup, but i find some documentations only the mention of data center and not the cloud container.

Comment: my bet is that you have to give a little bit more context to your question to get an answer. good luck!

Comment: I think he is trying to search difference between data center and cloud container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Containers are just a term to describe virtual environments like an LXC or OpenVZ created containers. These are light weight and much more efficient than VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Containers hold the components necessary to run application files, environment variables and libraries, and because the host OS also constrains the container’s access to physical resources (e.g., CPU and memory), a single container cannot consume all of a host’s physical resources. Instead, multiple isolated systems, “containers” run on a single control host and access a single kernel.